# how can one display the sum of a group of numbers from firebase in a texview

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im working with android firebase and have managed to get the sum of a group of values from firebase and display it in logcat. Only i want to display this sum in a TextView, how would I do that? Here is my code

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

     public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            heroList.clear();
            int total = 0;

            for(DataSnapshot artistSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                Integer rating = artistSnapshot.child("editTextCalories").getValue(Integer.class);

                Hero hero = artistSnapshot.getValue(Hero.class);
                heroList.add(hero);


                total += Hero.getTotal(rating);

            }
            Log.d("Tag", total + "");
            NameList adapter = new NameList(MainActivity.this, heroList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        }
```

Comment: `((TextView)findViewById(R.id.myAwesomeTextView)).setText(""+total)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set the value to the text view in `onDataChange`, pretty much in the same spot where you already log it:

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    heroList.clear();
    int total = 0;

    for(DataSnapshot artistSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

        Integer rating = artistSnapshot.child("editTextCalories").getValue(Integer.class);

        Hero hero = artistSnapshot.getValue(Hero.class);
        heroList.add(hero);


        total += Hero.getTotal(rating);

    }
    Log.d("Tag", total + "");
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.myAwesomeTextView)).setText(""+total)
    NameList adapter = new NameList(MainActivity.this, heroList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
```